# On a command line Windows 10 doesnt show which Python version is installed

Tags: python, windows

I have installed Python 3.8 but neither Windows Powershell or Command Prompt show which Python version is installed on my Windows 10. I tried different combinations commands but nothing works. `python --version`, `python -v`. Am I missing something?

Comment: Use the `path` command to get a list of possible locations and figure out the first one on the list that has `python` installed.

Comment: Find your installation: dir C:\python*

Comment: Probably you installed 3.8 from python.org, but the current search `PATH` is finding the "python.exe" appexec link to "AppInstallerPythonRedirector.exe", which opens the Microsoft Store to install the store-app distribution of Python. "AppInstallerPythonRedirector.exe" silently fails instead of loading the store if command-line arguments are passed. Getting the fix pushed into Windows is taking a long time. If you never plan to use the store-app distro, then just go into the app settings and disable all of the appexec aliases for "python*.exe", "pip*.exe", and "idle*.exe".

Comment: *"Nothing works"* is not a sufficient problem statement. See [ask].

Comment: I have stated in the header that I cant retrieve Pyhton version from a command line. "nothing works" was just confirmation that none of the commands I used are working. Im not sure in what other way I cant articulate that something doesnt work.

Comment: Instead of Python --version, I just used py --version and it works. I think py is new alias for Python

Comment: Again, open the apps settings, click on "app execution aliases", and disable the app installer aliases for "python.exe" and "python3.exe", which are only meant to open the store. They fail silently when passed a command-line option such as `-V`. Also, if you didn't configure Python to add it to environment variables, modify your installation and select the option to do so. Then python.exe should work fine in a new instance of your preferred CLI shell (CMD, PowerShell, bash) that's executed from the desktop shell (Explorer).

Comment: py is not the "new alias" for Python. It's a multi-version launcher that allows running any installed version of standard Python. For example, `py -3.9-32` runs a 32-bit installation of Python 3.9, assuming one is installed. The launcher locates the installation, and spawns and waits for its python.exe.

Comment: I disabled app installer aliases for "python.exe" and "python3.exe" and when I installed Python I checked option to add it to env variables. I checked env var and Python is there. Still if using Python in command I get message "python : The term 'python' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script
file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.". On the other hand "py" works fine. I have installed Python 3.7.7

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you need:

```
python3 --version
```

This is because you are using python 3, not an earlier version.

Comment: I tried it and many other command command versions/variations but still it doesnt show anything.